# How to search a text file for a string in PHP

Tags: php, search

Hi I have a text file (one word per line) and I want to search it. I am using the following code but that only searches the last line. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
    $lines = file('names.txt');
$uid = $_POST['name'];
$found = false;

foreach ($lines as $line){
    if ($line == $uid)
        $found = true;
}

if ($found)
    echo 'YES';
else
    echo 'NO';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your approach, but you need to strip the newline feeds at the end of the lines:

```
if (trim($line) == $uid)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use `file('names.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` that prevents a newline at the end of each array element.

Answer (score 1):

Make var_dump of $lines for see if is array or not? If not than file not seperated \r\n

and for compare string use http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcasecmp.php